# How can I count the number of rectangular in column?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I have a this picture.

[image]

and make rectangular cover the letter like this.

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/project/t2.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(img,None,None,0.4,0.4)
#cv2_imshow(image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,190,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
ctrs,_= cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(36,255,12),2)
    if w >2  and h > 2:
      #os.chdir('{}'.format(folder_out))
      roi = cv2.resize(roi,(224,224))
      #cv2.imwrite('letter{}.jpg'.format(i), roi)
cv2_imshow(image)
```

this's the result.

[image]

And I want to count the number of rectangular in column like

[image]

I want a code that can count the number of rectangular in column.
Could you please Help me solve this problems. TT

May be you have easy solution!!

Comment: Get the letters' centroids and check their horizontal coordinate - similar (very close) horizontal coordinate means they are part of the "same column".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not optimum (three for loops) but this works.
It should be optimized in case you have a lot of boxes.
It basically checks every items and compare them to the already recorded boxes.
If the current box has an intersection with one of the box in a group, then it is added to that group.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('./input.jpg')
image = cv.resize(img, None, None, 0.4, 0.4)

gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 190, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
ctrs, _ = cv.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
bounding_rectangles = []

for i, _ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(_ctr)
    bounding_rectangles.append([x, y, w, h])
    _roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 2)
    
    if w > 2 and h > 2:
        roi = cv.resize(_roi, (224, 224))
        
cv.imshow("Output", image)
cv.waitKey(0)

groups = [[bounding_rectangles[0]]]
added_index = [0]

for i, rect_item in enumerate(bounding_rectangles[1:]):
    group_found = False
    
    for j, group_items in enumerate(groups):
        
        for k, group_item in enumerate(group_items):
            if (group_item[0] <= rect_item[0] <= group_item[0] + group_item[2]) and i + 1 not in added_index:
                added_index.append(i + 1)
                groups[j].append(rect_item)
                group_found = True
                break
                
        if group_found is True:
            break
                
    if group_found is False:
        added_index.append(i + 1)
        groups.append([rect_item])

print(f"Groups found: {len(groups)}")

for i, item in enumerate(groups):
    print(f"Group {i + 1}: Box quantity = {len(item)}")
```

Comment: Note: I tested it with the second image you gave (no C nor E).

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's work!! Can I ask one more question. How can I find a max box?

Comment: what do you mean by "max" ?

Comment: I can do it! Thank you!!