# How to separate the position of letters and numbers in image?

Tags: python, algorithm, image, opencv, google-colaboratory

## The picture with letters and number

[image]

I crop each of letter and number like this

[image]

By follow this code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/S__23363591.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(img,None,None,0.4,0.4)
#cv2_imshow(image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,190,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
ctrs,_= cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(36,255,12),2)
    if w >2  and h > 2:
      #os.chdir('{}'.format(folder_out))
      roi = cv2.resize(roi,(224,224))
      #cv2.imwrite('letter{}.jpg'.format(i), roi)
cv2_imshow(image)
```

I want to group pictures of the same colume to save in same folder like this

[image]

And each folder I want to save pictures of letters and numbers separate folder like this

[image]

Then name the images in order like this

[image]

I want the code that can save the images separate folder and name in order like
picture above. Could you please Help me solve this problems. TT

Comment: it seems like the column part is almost done. you have the contours x values. you can group contours to columns. in the separation to digits or characters, maybe it's an overkill(i saw below you didn't like the pytesseract option), but maybe you can use mnist pre trained model to see if a crop is predicted as a digit WITH HIGH confidence.

Comment: Could you please help write the code.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087319/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-rectangular-in-column

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

using tesseract

```
# image = your_bounding_letter_or_number
from pytesseract import pytesseract, Output

rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results = pytesseract.image_to_osd(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)
```

look at that : https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/python-for-character-recognition-tesseract

with an algorithm, you can manage positions (columns), and meaning (letter or number)

Comment: I want a code that not use pytesseract. I have my model to predicted the letters. And I want to save the images separate folder.